# Update item in ko.ObservableArray

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, durandal, single-page-application

I have a small question that i want to find one item by its property and i want to update the same item , also it should reflect in collection.

**I am not using knockout util library.**

```
 Choice = function (id, text, order, selected) {
            this.Text = ko.observable(text);
            this.ID = ko.observable(id);
            this.Order = ko.observable(order);
            this.Selected = ko.observable(selected);
        },
Question = function (questiontext, id, order) {
            this.QuestionName = ko.observable(questiontext);
            this.QuestionId = ko.observable(id);
            this.QuestionOrder = ko.observable(order);
            this.Choices = ko.observableArray([]);
            this.UserResponse = ko.observable();
            this.Inputs = ko.observable(new Input());
        },
```

i want to find question no 3 and i want to update items choice information and added to Questions.

Any help on this.

Comment: Not enough code to go on. Show your overall viewmodel (or at least a simplified version of it).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `questions` refers to the `ObservableArray` which contains the list of `Question`s on your view model:

```
function find(array, predicate) {
    array = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(array);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        if (predicate(array[i]))
            return array[i];
}

var question = find(questions, function (q) { return q.QuestionId == 3; });
var choices = question.Choices;
// Update, add or do anything with `choices`
```

Things you might want to do after:

- Add an argument to specify the context in which the predicate runs.
- Add an argument to specify the index to start the search at.
- Create pseudo-arrays for your collections and augment their prototypes with the function, using `this` instead of the first argument.
- Optimize for performance (limit lookups).
- Implement a `findAll` variant that returns an array of all matches.
- Think about using a third-party library to help with all of this until these kinds of features get [standardized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Some third-party libraries are very good with all of this; it really depends on how extensively you'll need to manipulate these structures. Don't add a dependency for no reason, but don't burden yourself either by reinventing the wheel when it's not the component's goal.

**Edit:** Typo -- should mention I didn't run the code, please don't copy-paste blindly.